# How to implement elapsed millis as the timer for my motor spinning time?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have been using delay() as the function for my motor spinning time. However, at the same time, I need to calculate the rpm of my motor. Delay() function have to make it impossible for me to get the rpm whilst the motor spin. I have learned that I needed to use Elapsed millis as a replacement for delay() for my timing.

I have tried it and to no avail, I did not get the result in wanted. Yes, the motor spin according to the speed that I desired, however, it does not spin according to the time I wanted. It kept on spinning non-stop till I have to disconnect the power supply.

So, my question is, how do I implement the elapsed millis as my timer for my spinning motor?
please, guys, help me with this... Just guide me through and give me guidance.

This is my code that I have tried using elapsed millis. Any suggestion is welcome.

```
#include <elapsedMillis.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>  // Comes with Arduino IDE
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);  // Set the LCD I2C address
elapsedMillis timeElapsed;

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9,8,7,6}; //row pinouts of the keypad (L1, L2, L3, L4)
byte colPins[COLS] = {5,4,3}; //column pinouts of the keypad (R1, R2, R3)
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );


void setup()
{ 

  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(20,4);
  myservo.attach(11);

   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("S=");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("T=");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("S=");
  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print("T=");
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print("S=");
  lcd.setCursor(10,1);
  lcd.print("T=");
  lcd.setCursor(10,2);
  lcd.print("RPM");

}


 void loop()

{ 

  int stage1speed = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(2,0);
  lcd.print(stage1speed);
  lcd.print("sv");
  int stage1time = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print(stage1time);
  lcd.print("sec");

  int stage2speed = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(2,2);
  lcd.print(stage2speed);
  lcd.print("sv");
  int stage2time = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(2,3);
  lcd.print(stage2time);
   lcd.print("sec");


  int stage3speed = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(12,0);
  lcd.print(stage3speed);
  lcd.print("sv");
  int stage3time = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(12,1);
  lcd.print(stage3time);
  lcd.print("sec");





   if ( stage1speed > 0 && stage1time > 0 && stage2speed > 0 && stage2time > 0 && stage3speed > 0 
        && stage3time > 0 )

   {

    if(timeElapsed <= 1000*stage1time)

    {

     myservo.write(stage1speed);

     }

    if(timeElapsed <= 1000*stage2time)

    {

     myservo.write(stage2speed);

     }

    if(timeElapsed <= 1000*stage3time)

    {

     myservo.write(stage3speed);

     }
  }

}



int getTheNumber()
{
    char buffer[4];
    // Input up to 3 numbers until we find a * or #
    int i=0;
    while (1)
    {
        char key = keypad.getKey();

        // If it's a number AND we have space left, add to our string
        if ('0' <= key && key <= '9' && i < 3)
        {
            buffer[i] = key;
            i++;        
        }
        // If it's a * or #, end
        else if ('#' == key && i > 0)
        {
            // Null terminate
            buffer[i] =0; 
           int value = atoi(buffer);  // Convert to an integer
            break;
        } 

    }
    return atoi(buffer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`delay()` is only the tip of the iceberg. The problem with `delay()` is
that it is a *blocking* function: nothing else can be done during the
delay. If you want to control your motor and at the same time be
responsive to the user, you must avoid blocking your program. This means
not only getting rid of `delay()`, but also getting rid of *any blocking
function*.

Here your problem is on `getTheNumber()`. This function blocks until the
user is done typing the number. Try to rewrite it in a non-blocking
fashion. For example, it could return `-1` on every call as long as the
user is not done typing the number. On the first call after the user is
done it would return the valid value. If you manage to write everything
non-blocking, then you `loop()` will restart very often, and the program
will work with no significant latency.

As for managing the servo stages, simplest thing  would be to write a
[finite state machine](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/the-finite-state-machine/). I would write it with four states: IDLE,
STAGE1, STAGE2 and STAGE3. The transitions STAGE1 → STAGE2 → STAGE3 →
IDLE would be time-based, using the `elapsedMillis` object to track the
time spent in each state. The transition IDLE → STAGE1 would be
triggered by the user input.

```
static enum { IDLE, STAGE1, STAGE2, STAGE3 } state;
switch (state) {
    case IDLE:
        if (userRequestedToStartAgain()) {
            myservo.write(stage1speed);
            state = STAGE1;
            timeElapsed = 0;
        }
        break;
    case STAGE1:
        if (timeElapsed >= stage1time) {
            myservo.write(stage2speed);
            state = STAGE2;
            timeElapsed = 0;
        }
        break;
    case STAGE2:
        if (timeElapsed >= stage2time) {
            myservo.write(stage3speed);
            state = STAGE3;
            timeElapsed = 0;
        }
        break;
    case STAGE3:
        if (timeElapsed >= stage3time) {
            myservo.write(idleValue);
            state = IDLE;
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your suggestions... I really appreciate it.  I 'll give it a try based on your suggestions.thanks so much ..

Comment: Sir, I have to build userRequestedToStartAgain() function?? I don't understand that..care to elaborate it for me..

Comment: @rjadkins: You may consider that call to `userRequestedToStartAgain()` as pseudo-code. It means _you_ have to decide _when_ the cycle is supposed to start, presumably on the basis of some user input. Then you write the `if (...)` condition for the IDLE → STAGE1 transition.

Comment: how do I do that?? I'm very confused right now. Forgive me, sir, I'm new to Arduino programming and this finite state machine is new to me. I am trying to understand the state machine. The transition from state to state really confuses me. In a typical switch statement, I understand that we can choose the cases in the switch statement, however, trying to move case to case or state to state in the switch statement is really new to me. So the transition part is a bit hard for me. Please help me, sir, trying to understand this transition.

Comment: @rjadkins: Then you should probably take some time to study the subject. See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) for a general background on the concept of FSM, and [Majenko's tutorial](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/the-finite-state-machine/) for an introduction of the FSM as an Arduino programming technique.

Comment: I don't know if I even have time Sir, this project is due soon.  I have been using delay() for this project without out realising  that delay() pause the whole programming, thus unable for other function to work. The delay() have made my program unable to read the rpm function whilst the motor spin when I use delay() as the timer.

Comment: Mr. Edgar Bonet, can you give a suggestion regarding the userRequestedToStartAgain() ?? I find it hard trying to understand the state machine.

Comment: @rjadkins: It could be something like `userJustTyped('*')` or similar.

Comment: I'm using a 4x3 keypad. How do I put it in the code??  is it just like this:  if (userJustTyped('*') ? or   if (key== '*')? so far i have tried the key=='*' , nothing happen. Forgive me, sir, I am totally having trouble understanding this.